# Number of distinct prime divisors given $\phi(n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose that $a = 2^kb,$ where $b$ is odd. If $\phi(x) = a,$ prove that $x$ has at most $k$ odd prime divisors.

Answer (score 3):

If the prime factorization of $x$ is $2^a \cdot p_1^{a_1} p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_l^{a_l}$, where $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_l$ are odd primes, then
$$\phi(x)=2^{\max(a-1,0)} p_1^{a_1-1}p_2^{a_2-1}\cdots p_l^{a_l-1}(p_1-1)(p_2-1) \cdots (p_l-1) = 2^k \cdot b$$
Note that $p_j-1$ is even for all $j \in \{1,2,\ldots,l\}$. Hence, if $l > k$, we have $2^l \vert \phi(x)$, since we know that $2$ divides $p_j-1$ for all $j \in \{1,2,\ldots,l\}$. This gives a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If the prime factorization of $x$ is $p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_r^{a_r}$, then
$$\phi(x)=\phi(p_1^{a_1})\cdots\phi(p_r^{a_r})=p_1^{a_1-1}(p_1-1)p_2^{a_2-1}(p_2-1)\cdots p_r^{a_r}(p_r-1).$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Let $x= p_1^{a_1} \times p_2^{a_2} \times \dots p_m^{a_m} $

$\phi (x)=\phi( p_1^{a_1}) \times \phi( p_2^{a_2}) \times \dots \phi( p_m^{a_m})$

$ \phi(x)= \prod _{i=1}^m p_i^{a_i}(1- \dfrac{1}{a_i})$

$\prod _{i=1}^m p_i^{a_i}(1- \dfrac{1}{a_i}) =n \prod _{i=1}^m (1-\dfrac{1}{a_i})=2^k \times b. $

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I can prove that such $k \gt 0$ does not exist.
If $a$ has only odd divisors, then we can express $a$ as product these odd numbers. Product odd numbers is always odd number($(2u+1)(2v+1)=4uv+2u+2v+1=2z+1$-is odd). Number $2^kb$ can be odd only if $k=0$ and $b$ is odd, for $k\gt0$ is $2^kb$ always even.
So i think, that number $2^kb$ for $k\gt{0}$ must contains min.$k$ primes equals to $2$ and this I can prove.
If, as you suppose, the $a$ is product only of odd numbers, then
$a = (2a_1+1)(2a_2+1)(2a_3+1)...$ and this product can we express as $a=2u+1$.
If $k\gt{0}$ then $2^kb$ is even, and even number we can get only as product (even$\cdot$even), (even$\cdot$odd), (odd$\cdot$even), but never as (odd$\cdot$odd).